# Formatting numbers not raising error in Turtle Window

Tags: python, json, formatting, python-turtle

I have this Turtle Graphic that creates a message box where you can insert a integer.
This works until I decide to add a format which adds commas for every 3rd place value.
When it does it raises a ValueError.

Here is what it should have done:

```
bettedc = 10000

print(f'User betted {bettedc}$')
---------------------------------
User betted 10,000
```

This is the code involved in the error.

```
import turtle
import json

with open("data.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)


def betcurrency():
 try:
    global bettedc

    bettedc = turtle.textinput('Bet money.',
    f'You have {data["money"]:,}$. Remember, you can only bet money you have.')

    if int(bettedc) > data["money"]:
        print("User tried to bet what they didn't have.")
        betcurrency()
    elif int(bettedc) < 0:
        print('User tried to bet a negative amount.')
        betcurrency()
    else:
        print(f'User betted {bettedc:,}$')  # This line is where the error happens. It can be avoided if I remove :,
 except ValueError:
    print("User wrote word or a float number.")
    betcurrency()
```

You probably won't need this but here is the .json file.

```
{"money": 100000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake I made here... I forgot that `bettedc` is a string.

The solution is in the `else:` statement.

```
print(f'User betted {int(bettedc):,}$')
```